# can i use keywords as arguments in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework, keyword, robotframework-ide

I want to replace ${assertion_Keyword} by  `Screen Should Contain` or `Screen Should  Not Contain` so i want to put an Argument like a keyword

```
check_element_and_its_representation      
    [Arguments]    ${assertion_Keyword}    ${payload}    ${on_click_payload}     
    ${assertion_Keyword}    ${payload}
    SikuliLibrary.Click    ${payload}    
    Screen Should Contain    ${on_click_payload}
```

With this code i code a syntax error no keyword found : 
[image]

How can this action be possible? is there other ways to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Run Keyword command will help you with that. Below is an example inspired on your example code. I've commented out the Sikuli keywords, but kept them in place and added two keywords to mock those found in the Sikuly Library.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC Screen Should Contain
    Check Element And Its Representation    Screen Should Contain    payload    on_click_payload

TC Screen Should Not Contain
    Check Element And Its Representation    Screen Should Not Contain    payload    on_click_payload


*** Keywords ***

Check Element And Its Representation      
    [Arguments]    ${assertion_Keyword}=Screen Should Contain    ${payload}=None    ${on_click_payload}=None     
    Run Keyword    ${assertion_Keyword}    ${payload}
    # SikuliLibrary.Click    ${payload}    
    # Screen Should Contain    ${on_click_payload} 

Screen Should Contain
    [Arguments]    ${var}
    Log    Screen Should Contain

Screen Should Not Contain
    [Arguments]    ${var}
    Log    Screen Should Contain
```

Comment: So in this case we cannot use default keyword without redefine them ? 
Because  `Screen Should Contain` or  `Screen Should Not Contain` require one argument and if i use `Run Keyword    ${assertion_Keyword}    ${argument_to_take}` it doesn't work because of argument numbers

Comment: This can be done by adding default values to the arguments. See the updated example.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what i mean? the goal is to not redefine Both Keywords `Screen Should Contain` and `Screen Should Not Contain` and use the default ones when you want to call them in the place of `${assertion_Keyword}`. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes. Just remove these in the example and load the Sikuli. These are just placeholders because I didn't want to call the actual ones.